# Jest tests failing on Github Action but pass locally

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs, code-coverage, github-actions

Context: I have about ~100 test suites with a total of ~600 tests (which contain asynchronous tests as well as synchronous tests). I'm using `yarn test --coverage` to run the tests and generate a coverage report, and when executing this command locally all of the tests pass (and the coverage report is created) as expected.

However, I'm attempting to generate a test coverage report in a Github Action in order to upload the coverage report to a code coverage tool for analysis. To do this, I'm running `yarn test --coverage` in the Github Action. When executing this command in the Github Action, it has failed 100% of the time (with 2-3 specific tests always being the cause for the failure). For reference, this is my Github Action:

```
name: Example Action

on:
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, reopened, synchronize]
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  nodejs:
    name: Example Action
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    timeout-minutes: 20

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Set Node Version
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: 12
      - name: yarn install
        run: yarn install
      - name: yarn coverage
        run: yarn test --coverage
```

I investigated into why this would happen and realized that it could possibly be due to the "low-resources" available on the machine running the Github Action. In other words, since the container running the Github Action has fewer cores to work with, it seems like Jest is only allowing 1 worker thread to be spawned (as opposed to the many threads that would be spawned locally to run the tests). To test if this was possibly the issue, I ran `yarn test --coverage --maxWorkers=1` locally, and as I expected the same tests that were failing on the Github Action were now failing locally (however now it was only 1-2 tests failing of the original 2-3 tests, depending on the run).

My question is, why would the number of threads being used by Jest effect the passing/failing of a test? And also, does anyone have any guidance on any way to investigate/fix this issue?

Comment: I'm encountering the same issue, but in Jenkins. When running tests locally everything is fine but when running tests in Jenkins specific tests are falling. When setting the `--runInBand` option all tests are passing but is very slow.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Locally all the tests are passing with 100% coverage. But In Github Actions, all tests are passing but the coverage is less and the threshold does not meet so the unit tests step is failing.